# Uncaught TypeError when using .replace() on HTML5 data attribute storing numbers retrieved with jQuery $.data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeerror, custom-data-attribute

I am storing database values in HTML5 data attributes via jQuery while first escaping them to be HTML attribute safe, and it works fine with `String`s.

However, if I've stored a number that doesn't begin with `0`, it always gives, for example when the value is `1000`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object 1000 has no method 'replace'

How can this be fixed?

**html escaper/unescaper**

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
        .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
        .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
        .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
        .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
        .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
function unescapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
        .replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
        .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
        .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
        .replace(/&quot;/g, "\"")
        .replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
}
```

I `$.append()` the element with a `String` with this `data-sortValue="'+sortValue+'"` as the HTML5 data.

I try to read it again in another function with `unescapeHtml(String($(this).data('sortvalue')))`.

Comment: You have a typo here : `unescapeHtml(String($(this).data('sortvalue')))`. You are using `sortvalue` instead of `sortValue`. Is this also in your code ?

Comment: @Brewal jQuery won't recognize `data-sortValue` with `$.data('sortValue`)`, but it will with `$.data('sortvalue`)`

Comment: Yes you are right. That just slipped my mind. But you shouldn't use uppercase in data-* attributes either :
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Comment: @Brewal yeah, was wondering if that was causing the problem.  just was hoping i didn't have to copy paste all the corrections :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not handling the case where `unsafe` could be `undefined` or `unsafe` is a number/boolean.

Here we can check whether `unsafe` exists and `replace` function is available.

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe && $.isFunction(unsafe.replace) ? unsafe
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&#039;") : unsafe;
}
function unescapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe && $.isFunction(unsafe.replace) ? unsafe
    .replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
    .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
    .replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
    .replace(/&quot;/g, "\"")
    .replace(/&#039;/g, "'") : unsafe;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RSKbz/2/)

Comment: are you sure it's an issue of `undefined`?  It has value, I just can't seem to cast `number` as `string`

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy this will handle that case also because we are checking whether the `replace` function is presnet

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy if it is a number we can return it without processing it